# If I produce an alphanumeric string with length k, how many n strings must I produce to get a duplicate equal to a 1% chance?

Tags: probability

I'm terrible when it comes to probability.  The alphanumeric string consist of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789' which is 36 possibilities.  If the string is k length (for example 8 alphanumeric chars long) how many n number of strings must I produce for a 1% chance of a duplicate?

Would the math look like this?

$$
\frac{n}{36^{k}} = \frac{0.01}{1}
$$

$$
n = 36^{k}(0.01)
$$

If so, then I'm sorry I wasted everyone's time, I just wanted to make sure and no this isn't homework or anything like that.

Comment: I am confused by the wording of the problem.  It would help if the problem could
be clarified with a specific example.  Suppose that $k = 8$, and $n = 12$.  Further
suppose that the string is "abcdefgh".  By $n$ string, are you referring to a
12 character string, where each character can be any one of 36 symbols?  That is,
do you intend that there are $36^{(12)}$ equally likely 12 character strings?  ...see next comment

Comment: Further,
when you say "produce ... a duplicate", do you mean that a specific 12 character
string duplicates the "abcdefgh" string if and only if "abcdefgh" occurs somewhere
in the 12 character string as a **sub-string**?  Further, are you asking, if $r$
is the number of (random) 12 character strings created, what is the smallest value
for $r$ so that the chances that "abcdefgh" occurs as a substring in at least one
of the $r$ strings is $\geq 0.01.$  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: See my comment to Sil's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the way you produce the string, if it's randomly, then you would need to know the probability distribution. If we assume uniform distribution (each character is equally likely, which is common in practice in similar tasks), then for strings of length $k$ with $c$ possible characters on each position, we have total of $c\cdot c \cdots c=c^k$ of possibilities. Since the distribution is assumed uniform, each of the possibilities is equally likely, so $1/c^k$ of generating any specific string.  Now to calculate collision probabilities, it is basically a version of [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) (with really big numbers).

So suppose we want to generate $n$ of such strings, and see what is the probability there *is not* a duplicate. The first generated string can be any of $c^k$. The second must be just different from the previous one, so we have only $c^k-1$ possibilities. Similarly for third $c^k-2$, and so on. So probability there is no duplicate after generating $n$ strings this way is
$$
\frac{c^k}{c^k} \cdot \frac{c^k-1}{c^k}\cdots \frac{c^k-(n-1)}{c^k}=\frac{(c^k)!}{(c^k-n)!c^k}=\frac{n!\binom{c^k}{n}}{(c^k)^n}.
$$

Now the probability that there *is* a duplicate is simply the complement
$$
p=1-\frac{n!\binom{c^k}{n}}{(c^k)^n}.
$$

For numbers of the magnitude as in your problem, it is more practical to approximate the probability, for example as

$$
p \approx 1 - e^{-n^2/(2c^k)},
$$
or
$$
n \approx \sqrt{2c^k\ln \left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)}.
$$

So for $c=36$, $k=8$ and $p=0.01$ we have $n \approx 238130$ of required strings (the exact value in this case is $n=238132$).

Comment: I upvoted and am impressed at your deciphering his post.  I thought his query's title : "how many $n$ strings" referred to strings of length $n \geq k$, rather than $n$ strings each of length $k$.  Hence my comment re *substrings.*  In retrospect, although it is still unclear, I *suspect* that your interpretation was *intended* by the OP, especially because my interpretation involves *substrings* which would represent a **bizarre** aspect to this type of math problem.

Comment: Thanks Sil, you could probably guess I'm a software developer and this helps justify a function I'm using since the likelihood of collision is so remote and to decrease the odds of a collision I'm using k = 16.

Comment: @Travis I thought it will be probably related to some one way function such as hashing functions. But keep in mind that however unlikely the collisions are, they can happen so you should not rely on them never happening (if you do, then you should have a mechanism to deal with those).